# how to return fail if numpy array is not specified values

Tags: python-3.x

I would like the code to return "fail" statement if the numpy array contains value that is not 0 or 10. Checking 2nd and 3rd column, as long as there is one value that doesn't satisfy the criteria, the code returns "fail". My code always return pass.

data file has the format:

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0
4 50 10 0
5 10 10 0
6 10 10 0    
7 10 10 0
```

---

```
data = np.loadtxt('datafile.txt')
x1, x2 = data[:,1], data[:2]

if (x1.any != 0 or x1.any !=10):
    x1label = 'fail'
else:
    x1label = 'pass'

if (x2.any !=0 or x2.any !=10):
    x2label = 'fail'
else:
    x2label = 'pass'

if (x1label == 'fail') or (x2label == 'fail'):
    label = 'fail'
else:
    label = 'pass'
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `any` before comparison, which mean you compare `bool` with `int`.

```
data = np.loadtxt('datafile.txt')
x1, x2 = data[:,1], data[:2]

if np.any(x1 != 0) or np.any(x1 !=10):
    x1label = 'fail'
else:
    x1label = 'pass'

if np.any(x2 !=0) or np.any(x2 !=10):
    x2label = 'fail'
else:
    x2label = 'pass'

if (x1label == 'fail') or (x2label == 'fail'):
    label = 'fail'
else:
    label = 'pass'
```

Comment: If i don't use any, it gets the following error    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @hamster you can use `np.any`, why not.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. I didn't see you have moved any before the comparison. It is now returning fail which is correct. But when i put into a loop, reading the second file, which should have given me "pass" , it isn't.

Comment: Instead of just 'datafile.txt', i now put it in a loop to read in several data files one-by-one and do the same evaluation. I am expecting the first to return fail, and the second to return pass. I am not sure how to write an example code under comment.

Comment: I think i know why doing the loop doesn't work. As a test, i change "50" in the data file to "10", your code should have returned "pass" but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, which i find it works.

```
    import numpy as np

    a_file = open('datafile.txt', 'r')
    LINES = a_file.readlines()
    a_file.close()

    for i in range(len(LINES)):
        line = LINES[i]
        TOKS = line.split()
        x1 = TOKS[1]
        x2 = TOKS[2]
        if (x1 != '0' and x1 != '10'):
            x1label = 'fail'
            break        
        else:
            x1label = 'pass'

        if (x2 != '0' and x2 != '10'):
            x2label = 'fail'
            break        
        else:
            x2label = 'pass'

    if (x1label == 'fail') or (x2label == 'fail'):
            label = 'fail'
    else:
            label = 'pass'
```